# How to pass regular expression in a list in Groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy

I have tried these things but it is not working for me:

```
def fileNames = [/ReadyAPI-\d.\d.\d.vmoptions/, 'loadtestrunner.bat', 'ready-api.bat', 'securitytestrunner.bat']

def fileNames = ['ReadyAPI-\\d.\\d.\\d.vmoptions', 'loadtestrunner.bat', 'ready-api.bat', 'securitytestrunner.bat']
```

What I am trying to do is that there will be one of the two files that will be present in the system which are:
'ReadyAPI-1.2.2.vmoptions' OR 'ReadyAPI-1.3.1.vmoptions'.

I am relatively new to Groovy so may be I am not seeing common problem. So, please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: Well, irrespective of groovy or any other language, when you ask a question and say "it is not working for me", how could we possibly guess what's wrong with it?  Tell us exactly what you're doing, and what happens that is "not working". I tried that first line in a code sample, and it matches file names with that pattern perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you trying to get the actual filename of the existing file, then put that name into the list? If so, see my answer below. If not, please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the filename first, then put it into the list. You can use Groovy's [`FileNameByRegexFinder`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/FileNameByRegexFinder.html) from `groovy.utils` like this to find that file with a regex:

```
def optionsFile = new FileNameByRegexFinder()
        .getFileNames('.', /ReadyAPI-\d.\d.\d.vmoptions/).first()

def fileNames = [optionsFile, 'loadtestrunner.bat', ...]
```

Note that the first parameter to `getFileNames()` is the base directory to search in, you will likely need to change that for your scenario.